# Failed to deploy settings to scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file

I am getting this error while creating the scratch org: 
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "name": "ProblemDeployingSettings",
  "message": "Failed to deploy settings to scratch org.",
  "exitCode": 1,
  "commandName": "OrgCreateCommand",
```

[image]
========== My DEF FILE ===========

```
{
    "orgName": "BUBBA TEST",
    "edition": "Enterprise",
    "features": ["ContactsToMultipleAccounts", "DeferSharingCalc", "PersonAccounts"],
    "settings": {
        "chatterSettings": {
            "enableChatter": false
        },
        "enhancedNotesSettings": {
            "enableEnhancedNotes": true
        },
        "nameSettings": {
            "enableMiddleName": true,
            "enableNameSuffix": true
        },        
        "opportunitySettings": {
            "enableOpportunityTeam": true
        },
        "quoteSettings": {
            "enableQuote": false
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me understand what's causing this?

Comment: What's the sourceApiVersion in your sfdx-project.json ? Can you try with API 48 if it's something different ? I tried with the same definition file and I can create the scratch org without any error.

Comment: Does the error repeat if you retry?

Comment: Thanks for the response(s)
It does keep throwing same error even after setting the ApiVersion in sfdx-project.json to 48.

Comment: @DavidReed yes, It repeats every time I try from windows. The funny thing is - it worked fine when I created scratch with same definition file and same version of CLI 7.50.0 from MacOS.

Comment: As this is the first answer on Google, I'd like to share what helped me. First I played around with removing different settings, and then I saw a post here: https://youtrack.jetforcer.com/issue/JF-2209 that suggested removing --json in the command, which gives more details about the error. In my case it was the enableSetPasswordInApi setting.
I received the following error: 
Error  shape/settings/Security.settings  Security  Property 'enableSetPasswordInApi' not valid in version 51.0

I removed that clause and was able to create the scratch org.

Comment: Removing enableSetPasswordInApi fixed this issue for me. Annoying that --json doesn't yield the same output as not using it. Once I removed that, there was an explicit message saying that enableSetPasswordInApi wasn't valid in API 52.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For anyone struggling with the same above mentioned error while creating scratch org, I was able to create scratch org ***by downgrading my salesforcedx plugin version to : salesforcedx 47.18.0 (47.18.0)*** instead of latest at this moment(salesforcedx 48.5.1)

```
sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@47.18.0
```

Comment: hmm, here I am on sfdx-cli 7.61.0, and I went ahead and rolled back my plugins to 47.18 as suggested.. but.. no luck

Comment: Well, I have tried this option as well - re-install the CLI and it may fix this

Answer (score 11):

I faced the same issue, I noticed that the orgs were getting created but they haven't got linked with VSCode project. Did the below changes in my project-scratch-def.json file and it worked for me:

[image: Changes in project-scratch-def.json]

It looks like "EnableSetPasswordInApi" is now a feature instead of an entry in securitySettings for the latest sfdx cli version (sfdx-cli/7.105.0 at the moment which I am using). Hope that helps!

Comment: This work for me (sfdx-cli/7.94.3-a4e7c7955b)

Comment: This worked for me as well (sfdx-cli/7.121.8)

Comment: This worked as well!

Comment: `Not available for deploy for this API version
Property 'enableSetPasswordInApi' not valid in version 54.0`

Answer (score 2):

I had an newline at the end of my settings file. Removing this newline appeared to fix it for me.

Comment: Removing the blank final line worked for me too. And I then realized the orgs had been created despite of the error message, just without an alias.

Answer (score 1):

ANSWER FOUND, SEE EDIT BELOW

I'm having the same issue in Nov '22. I've created dozens of scratch orgs from this scratch-def with no problem up till now.

`A scratch org was created with username test-isdfasfdsai@example.com, but the settings failed to deploy due to:  Not available for deploy for this API version`

Has something changed that would break my scratch-def?
My scratch-def:

```
{
    "orgName": "Proton7Group",
    "hasSampleData": true,
    "edition": "Enterprise",
    "namespace": "myNamespace",
    "features": ["Communities", "PartnerCommunity", "ForceComPlatform"],
    "settings": {
        "orgPreferenceSettings": {
            "s1DesktopEnabled": true,
            "s1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
        },
        "communitiesSettings": {
            "enableNetworksEnabled": true
        }
    }
}
```

ANSWER:
Apparently, they changed how some of the settings should be configured. I was having issues with the orgPreferenceSettings. Now, instead of what you see above, the settings should be like this:

```
"settings": {
        "mobileSettings": {
            "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": true
        },
        "lightningExperienceSettings": {
            "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
        },
        "communitiesSettings": {
            "enableNetworksEnabled": true
        }
```

Comment: You aren't using force:org:beta:create. Try that.

Comment: force:org:beta:create doesn't work either.